# Error al instalar Paypal SDK Xamarin

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, xamarin, paypal

Estoy tratando de instalar el SDK de Paypal (1.7.0) y me sale el siguiente error:

> Could not install package 'PayPalCoreSDK 1.7.0'. You are trying to
>   install this package into a project that targets
>   'portable-net45+win+MonoTouch10+MonoAndroid10+xamarinmac20+xamarinios10',
>   but the package does not contain any assembly references or content
>   files that are compatible with that framework. For more information,
>   contact the package author.

¿Les ha pasado? ¿me podrían ayudar?

Por cierto mi current profile es el siguiente[image: current profile]

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que al parecer la dll de paypal no es [PCL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-mx/library/gg597391(v=vs.110).aspx),  por ello no podrías agregarla, en su lugar puedes usar el nuget [PayPal Plugin for Xamarin.Forms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PayPal.Forms/) ([Aquí hay documentación](https://github.com/AlejandroRuiz/PayPal.Forms)) o bien usar la [API Rest](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/) de paypal